# EmberJS Data hasMany sideloading with ActiveModelSerializers

Tags: ember-data, active-model-serializers

I'm using Ember Data canary build: `1.0.0-beta.8+canary.267214b9` together with a rails back-end and `ActiveModelSerializer`. My configuration on ember side looks like this:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend()

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend
  namespace: "api/v1"

App.Authentication = DS.Model.extend
  provider: DS.attr('string')
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')

App.User = DS.Model.extend
  username: DS.attr('string')
  email: DS.attr('string')
  authentications: DS.hasMany('authentication')
```

I have working `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relation for a model that isn't side loaded. The JSON for the relation look like this:

```
 {
   objectA: {
     property1: 'prop1',
     property2: 'prop2',
     objectB_ids: ['1','2']
   }
 }
```

At the moment I try to get a user model with multiple authentications to work. But there the authentications should be side loaded. It doesn't work for the following JSON:

**JSON - not working**

```
{
  authentications: [{ id:1, provider:"google" }],
  user: {
    id: '1',
    username: 'max',
    email: 'max@examle.com',
    authentication_ids:[1],
  }
}
```

But it does work for this:

**JSON - working**

```
{
  authentications: [{ id:1, provider:"google" }],
  user: {
    id: '1',
    username: 'max',
    email: 'max@examle.com',
    authentications:[1],
  }
}
```

The only useful information I found on the web is this SO question:

[Serialising async hasMany relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976329/serialising-async-hasmany-relationships)

Is this a bug in the `DS.ActiveModelSerializer` or did I miss some configuration?

**EDIT 1:**

In the docs of [DS.ActiveModelSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelAdapter.html) you can find the following:

> It has been designed to work out of the box with the activemodelserializers Ruby gem.

And the version with `authentication_ids:[...]` is the way, how the ActiveModelSerializers Ruby gem does it out of the box. So maybe it should be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue and `DS.ActiveModelSerializer` works as expected and did accept `_ids` array for side loaded models.

My problem was, that I had overwritten my `App.UserSerializer` with that:

```
 App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend
   # some custom logic
```

,but it has to be:

```
 App.UserSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend
   # some custom logic
```

Maybe someone has similar problems after changing from `DS.RESTSerializer` to DS.ActiveModelSerializer`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing what ActiveModelSerializer does with other conventions of Ember Data. You're working second example is correct. [This section](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions) describes the current expectation of JSON layout. The `_ids` is not present.

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Rails is omakase",
    "comments": ["1", "2"],
    "user" : "dhh"
  },

  "comments": [{
    "id": "1",
    "body": "Rails is unagi"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "body": "Omakase O_o"
  }]
}
```

The ActiveModelSerializer adapter allows you to pass underscored keys in your JSON instead of camelcased keys. For example, if your user had a camelcased name:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr()
```

Your JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "first_name": "kunerd"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but why does it work for models, that aren't sideloaded?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I mean it: the `_ids` field works on models where the associated models are loaded asynchronous, but it doesn't work for models where the associated models are side loaded in the same response. That seems a little bit inconsistent for me. Also have a look on my edit from yesterday, if you haven't already.